# how to find and filter last event for each unique Column - SQL query

Tags: mysql, select

i have a table in my DB called Events.
in this table there is event for every message i get and every step that was taken by system with it.

lets say

```
ID  class      Time             MessageID    Text
 1  message    6/6/2018 8:00    aaa          message received
 2  message    6/6/2018 8:01    aaa          message processed
 3  message2   6/6/2018 8:02    bbb          message received 
 4  message    6/6/2018 8:03    aaa          message send
 5  message2   6/6/2018 8:04    bbb          message processed
 6  message    6/6/2018 9:00    ccc          message received
 7  message    6/6/2018 10:00   ccc          message processed
```

from time to time i have a situation where some message just end up in phase **message processed**

i need to write query that would check all messages in selected day with class **message** and their last event is **message processed**
and give me result only that last row

thank you in advance

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to your question...

```
select ID, class, time, messageID, text
from Events
where class = 'message'
  and text = 'message processed'
  and time BETWEEN '2018-06-06 00:00:00' AND '2018-06-06 23:59:59'
order by ID desc
limit 1
```

Brief explanation:

The query searches all records that have the conditions in the where clause: class = 'message', text = 'message processed' and date time.

Then order in decreasing order by ID, and after ordering, the first found ID will be the last found in the table.

And then use the LIMIT command to return only the first record.

**Tip**: You shouldn't use a command like DATE(datecolumn) = '2018-06-06', because it poor the performance.

I hope I've helped!